# Difference between keras.evaluate() accuracy e manually calculated accuracy by prediction: Multilabel classification

Tags: keras, neural-network, predict, conv-neural-network, evaluate

I'm using keras to perform multilabel classification. I'm using '***binary_crossentropy***' as loss function, ***metrics=['accuracy']***, '***sigmoid***' as activation.

During the training I saw accuracy above the 90%, and also using ***evaluate*** on the test set I have something similar.
If I try to manually compute the accuracy using ***predict*** module the accuracy also on the training set dramatically leaves 45%.

This is the model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(8, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(N_qubits, N_qubits,2)))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=y_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))


adam_optimizer = keras.optimizers.adam()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=150, epochs=1000, verbose=1, validation_split=0.05)
```

Here where I use evaluate()

```
results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

Here when I use predict()

```
y_pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Please, show your code. How do you train, evaluate and predict values?

Comment: Why are you using 'binary_crossentropy' as your loss function while it is a multilevel classification? Use 'categorical_crossentropy'.

Comment: Again, it's hard to suggest anything without knowing what type of data are you using. Seems like it has been overfitted. Maybe you want to increase number of training data. Maybe you want to reduce dense layers. Or maybe using Conv2D(8) and Conv2D(16) is not what you want to use. Try using Conv2D(3) and MaxPool2D(2). I think it's hard to say something definite here.

Comment: I'm doing multilabel classification, and I read that binary_crossentropy is functional fort that. Categorical_crossentropy is used in multiclass classification for what I know. Am I wrong ?